# What openCV newest version is C++ Builder XE2

Tags: opencv, c++builder-xe2

I Search in [OpenCV](https://opencv.org/) homepage but i can't judge what version is compatible C++Builder XE2

So I have a question what version is newest version and that is compatible C++Builder XE2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are going to end up using an old version like **OpenCV 2.3.2** to be successful with this old IDE.